# AWS EC2 Instance Connect (browser-based SSH connection) keyboard shortcuts

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, browser, keyboard

I've lost both password and public key connection to my EC2 instance. But through browser ssh connection i can connect to my instance.

I want to modify the ssh_config to allow public key configuration. But while saving a file with `ctrl+o` on nano editor it's not working. Is there's a different keyboard bindings ?

Is there a list of shortcuts available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Shortcuts on linux machines:**

- **Save** "esc+esc+o"
- **Exit** "esc+esc+x"

And the other way to reconfigure ssh configuration was using a rescue instance:

- Mounting volume on rescue instance.
- Reconfiguring sshd_config file.
- Remounting volume on original ec2 instance

> [Reference](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-troubleshoot-sshd-config-edits/)